# C++ Boost multithreading inside a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am following Boost multithreading tutorial [here](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/c-multithreading-in-boost.10028/)
.  Following section 18.13, I try creating a class containing multiple threads as follows:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

class MultiTask
{
private:
    boost::thread_group threads;    // thread group
    boost::thread* thread_main;     // main thread
    boost::thread* thread_output;   // output thread
    boost::thread* thread_input;    // input thread
    boost::mutex stopMutex;
    bool stop;
    int i_in, i_out, i_main;
    string userInput;
public:
    // constructor
    MultiTask()
    {
        thread_main = new boost::thread(boost::ref(*this));
        thread_output = new boost::thread(&MultiTask::Callable_Out, this, 1000, boost::ref(i_out));
        thread_input = new boost::thread(&MultiTask::Callable_In, this, 1000, boost::ref(i_out), boost::ref(userInput));
        //threads.add_thread(thread_main);  // main thread = 0 // will throw -> boost thread: trying to join itself
        threads.add_thread(thread_output);  // output thread = 1
        threads.add_thread(thread_input);   // input thread = 2
        stop = false;
        i_in = 0;
        i_out = 0;
        i_main = 0;
        userInput = "";
    }
    // destructor
    ~MultiTask()
    {
        // stop all threads
        Stop();

        // show exit message
        cout << "Exiting MultiTask." << endl;
    }

    // start the threads
    void Start()
    {
        // Wait till they are finished
        threads.join_all();
    }

    // stop the threads
    void Stop()
    {
        // warning message
        cout << "Stopping all threads." << endl;

        // signal the threads to stop (thread-safe)
        stopMutex.lock();
        stop = true;
        stopMutex.unlock();

        // wait for the threads to finish
        threads.interrupt_all();
        threads.join_all();
    }

    void Callable_Out(int interval, int& count)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            //cout << "Callable_Out [" << count++ << "]" << endl;
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
    }

    void Callable_In(int interval, int& count, string& userInput)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            cout << "Callable_In [" << count++ << "]. Enter message: ";
            getline(cin, userInput);
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
    }

    // Thread function
    void operator () ()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            //cout << "Main [" << i_main++ << "]." << endl;
            //cout << "Main [" << i_main++ << "]. " << userInput << endl;
            if (userInput == "STOP")
            {
                try
                {
                    this->Stop();
                }
                catch(exception e)
                {
                    cout << e.what() << endl;
                }
            }

            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(1000));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MultiTask mt;
    mt.Start();
}
```

However, VS throws two of these errors:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2198 'void (__cdecl *)(boost::posix_time::millisec,int &,std::string &)': too few arguments for call mycpp c:\boost_1_66_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp 259

Can someone please help? This is from section 18.13. Also, I do not see where to input the arguments for CallableFunction() in that example. How can it be done in my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tutorial `CallableFunction` function takes only one parameter, it is passed as second parameter in thread constructor `new boost::thread(&CallableFunction, i);`.

In your case `Callable_Out` takes 2 parameters, one is missing, you should call

```
thread_output = new boost::thread(&Callable_Out, boost::posix_time::millisec(0), boost::ref(i_out));
```

and for `Callable_In` you call

```
thread_input = new boost::thread(&Callable_In, boost::posix_time::millisec(1), boost::ref(i_out), boost::ref(userInput));
```

Comment: So the Callable functions have the arguments input right on declarations?  Is there a documentation on that?  Thank you so much.

Comment: You use `boost::thread` so the best reference is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html , in **Launching threads** section there is described how to pass arguments into thread constructor object.

Comment: if I wish to put Callable_Out() and Callable_In() inside my class, how should my thread declarations be?

Comment: @CaTx Just copy and paste definition of `Callable_Out` and `Callable_In` into `MultiTask` class definition.  -  `class MultiTask {  .... ~MultiTask() { ... }   void Callable_Out (...) {}` but then you have to change constructor of *thread*, now body of thread is function member of class (not function) so you should put `this` after pointer to member (function member is executed for object pointed by this pointer) so `new boost::thread(&Callable_Out, this, boost::posix_time::millisec(0), boost::ref(i_out));` and in the same way you need to construct thread for `Callable_In` method.

Comment: @CaTx What compiler are you using ? Try this `new boost::thread(&MultiTask::Callable_Out, this, boost::posix_time::millisec(0), boost::ref(i_out))`

Comment: I am musing VC++.

Comment: Did  change `&Callable_Out` to `&MultiTask::Callable_Out` help ?

Comment: It did. Now, I add the function void operator () () into the class as seen in the edited post. However, it never gets called. Could you point out my error?

Comment: @CaTx You didn't create thread with `operator()` as body of thread, so you can add in MultiTask constructor this line `threads.add_thread(new boost::thread(&MultiTask::operator(), this));` or `threads.add_thread(new boost::thread(boost::ref(*this)));`

Comment: I tried that previously.  However, when I try to stop, it throws this error: boost thread: trying to join itself.  How can I fix this?

Comment: @CaTx You cannot call `join` on thread from function which is body of your thread - you call `Stop` (where `join` is called) from operator()() - this is body of your thread. Instead of `Stop()` in operator()() you should put `break` so `while (1) { if (userInput == "STOP") break; ... }`. See *Exception safety* from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/.

Comment: I change the code as above, and do not let main thread be added to the thread group.  Is it the right practice?  It seems to exit properly, but somehow Stop() gets called twice.  Can you give me some pointer?

Comment: OK, I called Stop() in operator() as well as in destructor.  Silly me.